# Not a real job ad

Tags: discussion, jobs

Seems they are only collecting developers to have a bigger database:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/99566/remote-ios-developer-upwork-pro

No idea where to report that, so please move if you know.

Comment: What about the listing makes you think it's fake? Just saying "it looks fake" isn't really helpful or constructive.

Comment: I think the confusion is because the careers ad links to a page to sign up to be a freelancer, using that site to find work.  So it's not an ad to work for that company directly per se, but to possibly  find work by being a member of that site. It's definitely not a fake company, it's even been mentioned on [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/elainepofeldt/2015/05/05/elance-odesk-becomes-upwork-today-odesk-brand-gets-phased-out/) and has its own [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwork).

Comment: @CRABOLO good points, worth a new answer IMO.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! While the company in question is certainly not a fake company, this listing does not adhere to our guidelines in that it does not offer a specific job, but rather the chance to find work through their website. As such we've expired the listing (will submit answer once question is re-opened).

Comment: @bluefeet why has this question got locked and OP deleted?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It was migrated from DIY, the user hasn't visited MSE yet, and it was closed here which locked it. The OP hasn't been deleted, they haven't created an account here yet.

Comment: @bluefeet for some reason I thought I've seen OP with account here. So, why reopening didn't unlock?

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for letting us know! As Crabolo mentioned, while the company in question is certainly not a fake company, this listing does not adhere to our guidelines in that it does not advertise a specific job, but rather the chance to find work through their website. As such we've expired the listing, and we've reached out to the client.

Answer (score 9):

From what I've seen, it a company that hire freelancers to work for other companies.

Nothing fake about it, and as long as people get their money nothing illegal and nothing to report.

Good luck finding a job.

---

For the record, if you have a **legitimate** reason to report a problem with a company, you have a "flag a problem" link in the right sidebar:

> [image]